# 2 where clauses on same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains votes that users make on their friends.

It is setup like this:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| user_id    | friend_id  | contender  | vote | 
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| 1695929578 | 1695529606 | 1695529577 |    1 | 
| 1695929578 | 1695529577 | 1695529606 |    0 |
| 1695929578 | 1695529721 | 1695529578 |    1 |
| 1695929578 | 1695529578 | 1695529721 |    0 |
| 1695929578 | 1695529580 | 1695529606 |    1 |
| 1695929578 | 1695529606 | 1695529580 |    0 |
| 1695929578 | 1695529606 | 1695529578 |    1 |
| 1695929578 | 1695529578 | 1695529606 |    0 |
| 1695929578 | 1695529577 | 1695529721 |    1 |
| 1695929578 | 1695529721 | 1695529577 |    0 |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
```

Each time a vote is made by the user (user_id) two rows are inserted. One row for the person who got the vote (vote = 1) and that persons contender, and then another row for the person who lost (vote = 0) and their contender.

With one query I want to be able to pass the users friends and get back how many votes are FOR and TOTAL votes for each distinct friend. It would return something like this:

```
+------------+-------------+
| family_id  | total_votes |
+------------+-------------+
| 1695529439 |           9 |
| 1695529577 |           9 |
| 1695529578 |           6 |
| 1695529580 |           7 |
| 1695529581 |           5 |
| 1695529606 |           7 |
| 1695529721 |           7 |
+------------+-------------+
```

The only difference is I want an extra column that will contain the votes_for that person so I can compare how many times they were contended to how many times they won.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 good use of code blocks to make a clear question ... unless I'm missing something :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Count()** will give you total number of votes.  **Sum()** will give you total of favorable votes.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Wow. I'm surprised I didn't think of that. Sometimes it takes someone else huh? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it does.  I think sometimes the left brain seizes up, and you need someone else's temporarily ... or a few hours on a boat, if that can be arranged.  :-)